# python - put a virtual fite to child process

Tags: python, sandbox, popen, virtual-file

I want to run a child process with `subprocess.Popen` and the application reads a config file.

The application connects to a database. Before I run the application I create an ssh tunnel and overwrite his config file to connect to the tunnel. (I run `/path/to/application/app.exe` and the application config is `/path/to/application/app.ini`)
But I dont want the user be able to read the config file. (user and password to the database)

Can I run the child process in a "sandbox" that when it wants to read the `/path/to/application/app.ini` the parrent process will put an own virtual config file?

Comment: Is this on Windows? Please specify the exact platform - solutions to this kind of problem tend to be very platform-dependent.

Comment: Yes I want it to run just on Windows.

Comment: Can the application be modified to optionally read the configuration from standard input (e.g. if given `-` or similar magic value for configuration file name)? Then you could use the standard `subprocess` features for writing to a subprocess pipes, which work on Windows just fine. This communication is language-independent and is normally invisible to non-privileged third-party observers.

Comment: What control do you have on `app.exe` (i.e. : can you alter source and recompile it) ? And where will parent app find user and password in a way not readable by user ?

Comment: the `app.exe` can be edited, Im working on the subprocess pipes and reading the config from stdin. The parent app is communicating with a server that sends the needed authentication data.